# $f:[a,0]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; a>0$ continuous and monotone increasing implies differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I had to prove an inequality of certain integrals using this continuous and monotone increasing function $f:[a,0]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $a>0$, with $f(0)=0$ and the $g$ is the inverse functions of the $f$. I managed to solve and to prove the inequality but at a certain step I assumed that $f$ differentiable. Can I assume differentiabilty, and if so, how can I prove it?

Comment: There are always $\sqrt[3]{x-x_0}$ and its cousins which are all not differentiable at $x_0$. And then there is Cantor's function ($+ x$, if you want it strictly increasing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f:[0,a]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$f(x)=2x-\frac{1}{2}a+|x-\frac{1}{2}a|=\begin{cases}x \text{ if }x\leq\frac{1}{2}a\\ 3x-a \text{ if }x\geq\frac{1}{2}a\end{cases}.$$ 
Note that $f$ is continuous, and monotone increasing but not differentiable.

Comment: In fact, almost any continuous piecewise linear functions will work as a counterexample.